# <authorization> Tag in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, active-directory, web-config

I am new to c# and Asp.net . Can any one please guide me how the [`<authorization>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.85).aspx) tag works?

Does `<allow roles="XYZ">` search in Active Directory or do we have to specify Active Directory explicitly?

If `<allow roles="XYZ">` searches in Active Directory, from where does it pick the name of Active Directory Domain Name?

Please help.

Comment: Hi Matias Thanks for help. Can you please answer my question. I know it might be silly but i am working on Asp.net for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your Active Directory name is MYDOMAIN, try something like:

```
<authorization>
<allow roles="MYDOMAIN\A-Security-Group"/>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Make sure that `MYDOMAIN\A-Security-Group` is a Security Group and not a Distribution Group.